# Access Swift Class in Objective C Header

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have been mixing Swift and Objective C just fine but I'm having issues gaining access to a Swift class from the HEADER file of Objective C.  I can do so successfully in the .m file.

Within the .h file I import the Xcode generated file that has the format "Appname-Swift.h".  However, in doing so I get the message that the file is not found.  I can do this same import in my .m file with no issue.  However, I need it in the .h file as I reference a Swift class that I need access to with public API.

How can I make use of the Swift class from the .h portion of Objective C?

Example:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"

@interface SelectedContactsVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) MapVC *mapVC;

@end
```

MapVC above is a Swift class.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Move `#import "MyApp-Swift.h"` to .m file.

And make your .h file as:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MapVC;

@interface SelectedContactsVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) MapVC *mapVC;

@end
```

Swift cannot generate "MyApp-Swift.h", if it's imported from Objective-C header, sort of mutual dependency thing maybe.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  Is adding the "@class" this way sort of like a forward declaration?

Comment: Yes, it teaches the compiler that the symbol is actually a class, but gives no other info. In most cases it's useful enough to avoid mutual dependency.

Comment: Awesome! exactly what I was looking for too. Thanks!